# CURL со стороны клиента

Tags: curl, php

Добрый день, есть такая задача, автоматизировать добавление объявлений, под клиента, согласно регламенту того или иного сайта (проще говоря по закону), но клиент боится что IP его сервера в итоге могут забанить (за массу). Как можно реализовать вызов того или иного скрипта на сайте партнера как-будто это человек, а не сервер?

Надеюсь мой вопрос понятен =)
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Написать код выполняющий нужные действия. Запускать на сайтах партнёров. Ваш Кэп.

Comment: @terantul т,е вариант с JavaScript и п.р не актуален?(

Comment: насколько я знаю сам js (jquery.$.post к примеру) не отправит данные с сайта партнёра на сторонний сайт, такое под силу php. Если на сайтах партнёрах разместить php скрипт отправки данных то вызывать через Ajax сам скрипт и будет счастье.

Comment: Судя по описанию Вы пытаетесь создать универсальный рассыльщик объявлений? Как то пытался подобное написать, времени много забирало, поэтому и забил. Но проблему с возможным баном по ip решил использованием curl_proxy.

Comment: через tor или любой друго анонимайзер, например